# Switch Statement is not adding to total variable

Tags: c++

So I am an absolute beginner, just started learning C++. We recently went over switch statements in class. I'm trying to make a personality test type program that uses a switch statement. However, I'm not sure I'm using it right. It refuses to add to my total variable.

Basically, I have the user input 1- 4 based off which answer they wish to choose, and then i want to tally points based off that answer. Here is what I have.  int inanswer is the variable that a "1" or a "4" is written to. int totalpts is the total points so far.

What am I doing wrong?

```
switch(inanswer){
    case '1':
        totalpts += 1;
        break;
     case '2':
        totalpts += 2; 
        break;
     case '3':
        totalpts += 3;
        break;
     case '4':
        totalpts += 4;
        break;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to see the whole program code. And it probably helps to have a `default` case: `std:cerr << "invalid input: " << inanswer << std::endl;`

Comment: @davidcs  It seems the labels should look like case 1: instead of case '1':

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "inanswer" is an int? You're testing it against character values. Try:

```
case 1:
    totalpts += 1;
    break;
 case 2:
    totalpts += 2; 
    break;
```

etc. instead of

```
 case '1':
    totalpts += 1;
    break;
 case '2':
    totalpts += 2;
    break;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(inanswer){
    case 1:
        totalpts += 1;
        break;
     case 2:
        totalpts += 2; 
        break;
     case 3:
        totalpts += 3;
        break;
     case 4:
        totalpts += 4;
        break;
}
```

Try it like this.
I hope inanswer is int.

Answer (score 0):

Your user will be typing a single char on the keyboard (without computing the integer that the letter implies) ?

Then try

```
switch(inanswer){
    case '1':
        totalpts += inanswer - '0';
        break;
    ... etc.
```

And then,  you can refactor the switch statement to perhaps:

```
switch(inanswer){
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':  totalpts += inanswer - '0';  break;

    default: {
       std::cerr << "user input out of range" << std::endl;
       assert(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this works: chars are implicitly converted to the integer needed, (Both  inanswer and the literal '0'.)